# why run exec command?

Tags: ubuntu, docker, kubernetes

What is the reason for this error? I dont understand . Command runs two pods but not running ubuntu pod?

```
vagrant@vagrant:~$ kubectl get po
NAME                   READY     STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
cassandra-2p4m0        0/1       Running   1          1d
k8s-master-127.0.0.1   3/3       Running   6          1d
nginx-app-6q4cn        1/1       Running   0          1h
nginx-i3bja            1/1       Running   4          1d
ubuntu-app-nuuyh       0/1       Running   11         1h
vagrant@vagrant:~$ kubectl exec -ti cassandra-2p4m0  -- /bin/sh
# ls
bin     dev   kubernetes-cassandra.jar  media  proc  run.sh   srv  usr
boot        etc   lib           mnt    root  sbin     sys  var
cassandra_data  home  lib64         opt    run   selinux  tmp
# exit
vagrant@vagrant:~$ kubectl exec -ti nginx-i3bja -- /bin/sh
# ls
bin   dev  home  lib64  mnt  proc  run   srv  tmp  var
boot  etc  lib   media  opt  root  sbin  sys  usr
# exit
vagrant@vagrant:~$ kubectl exec -ti ubuntu-app-nuuyh -- /bin/sh
error: Error executing remote command: Error executing command in container: container not found ("ubuntu-app")
```

Comment: Looks like your app might be in a crash loop (note RESTARTS:11). It's telling you it can't find the app. Try kubectl describe pod or kubectl logs to help debug why it's crashing.

Comment: try `kubectl logs -f <your_pod_name>` to see what is happening inside the pod and why it crashes.

Comment: There might not be any running container for your pod when requesting the log. Use `kubectl logs -p <pod_name>` to see the logs from the last exited container.

Comment: It seems that you don't have a running container in you ubuntu pod.

Comment: Just a tip, this is not the case here, but to avoid know the pod name, we can simply use the deploy name: `kubectl exec -ti deploy/ubuntu-app -- bash`

Answer (score 1):

The answer is already in the comments. The 11 restarts in the "get pods" output indicates that your container is repeatedly crashing. You can't exec into a dead container.

Look at the logs using "kubectl logs --previous ubuntu-app-nuuyh" to determine why if "kubectl get pod -o yaml ubuntu-app-nuuyh" doesn't provide enough information.